# how to make JSObject as array?

Tags: android, arrays, json, nullpointerexception

I have alot of link to get data from web hence I wanted to use loop to retrieve each URL's data but I had trouble in making JSObject as array.

```
JSONObject[] jsObjectallnewstype;
JSONArray[] jsonArrayallnewstype = null;

for(int i = 0; i < categories.length(); i++)
     {
        JSONObject c = categories.getJSONObject(i);
        // Storing each json item in variable
        String title = c.getString(TAG_TITLE);
        String url = c.getString(TAG_URL);  
        jsObjectallnewstype[i] = JSONFunction.getnewstype(title, url); //java.lang.NullPointerException                 
        jsonArrayallnewstype[i] = jsobjectallnewstype[i].getJSONArray(TAG_NEWLIST);
 }
```

This line `jsObjectallnewstype[i]` get null error although the log shows JSONFunction.getnewstype successfully retrieve the data.
And i am also worry tat second line `jsonArrayallnewstype[i]` could cause same error as well.

So JSObject cant be put as array? If so what are the alternative??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To fix your current code, you need to initialize your array.  This is why you are getting a NPE:

```
    JSONObject[] jsObjectallnewstype = new JSONObject[categories.length()];
    JSONArray[] jsonArrayallnewstype = new JSONArray[categories.length()];

    for(int i = 0; i < categories.length(); i++)
         {
            JSONObject c = categories.getJSONObject(i);
            // Storing each json item in variable
            String title = c.getString(TAG_TITLE);
            String url = c.getString(TAG_URL);  
            jsObjectallnewstype[i] = JSONFunction.getnewstype(title, url); //java.lang.NullPointerException                 
            jsonArrayallnewstype[i] = jsobjectallnewstype[i].getJSONArray(TAG_NEWLIST);
     }
```

Comment: Right, why I miss that !!
Thanks!